# Create custom response in .NET Core 5 with OData 8 controller

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I'm using OData 8 in .NET Core 5 with the `[EnableQuery]` attribute. Problem is when I want to return `Problem()` or `BadRequest("Some message")`, the API always returns some default OData `BadRequest` and  never the message I wanted (only when `[EnableQuery]` attribute is there).

Example:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(EnsureStableOrdering = false )]
public IActionResult GetList(ODataQueryOptions<List> queryOptions)
{
    if (queryOptions.Filter == null)
    {
        return BadRequest( "Filter is required for this endpoind!" );
    }

    try
    {
        queryOptions.Filter.Validator = new OdataCustomFilterValidator();
        this.BaseValidateQueryOptions(queryOptions);
    }
    catch (ODataException ex)
    {
        return this.BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }

    IQueryable<List> list = this._service.GetList();
    return this.Ok(list);
}
```

So in the above example, if the code gets to the first IF, i do not recieve this message but ALWAYS the same Odata error:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "",
> "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The requested resource is not a collection. Query options $filter, $orderby, $count, $skip, and $top can be applied only on collections.",
> "details": [],

Answer (score 1):

Hi you ran into this bug which was fixed in OData/WebApi https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2511 but it seems like it has not yet been migrated to AspNetCoreOData, A pull request [exists](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/pull/368) which when merged and published should allow you to continue with your use case which is valid.